# How to get depth of current node in JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treenode, depth

I have a JTree with a few nodes and subnodes. When I click on a node I want to know on which depth is it (0, 1, 3). How can I know that?

```
selected_node.getDepth();
```

doesn't return the depth of current node..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using `getLevel`. [`getLevel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#getLevel%28%29) returns the number of levels above this node -- the distance from the root to this node. If this node is the root, returns 0. Alternatively, if for whatever reason you have obtained the `Treenode[]` path (using `getPath()`) then it is sufficient to take the length of that array.

`getDepth` is different, as it returns the depth of the tree rooted at this node. Which is not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

basicaly you have to `Iterate` inside `JTree`, but `TreeSelectionListener` can returns interesting value, for example

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;

public class TreeSelectionRow {

    public TreeSelectionRow() {
        JTree tree = new JTree();
        TreeSelectionListener treeSelectionListener = new TreeSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent treeSelectionEvent) {
                JTree treeSource = (JTree) treeSelectionEvent.getSource();
                System.out.println("Min: " + treeSource.getMinSelectionRow());
                System.out.println("Max: " + treeSource.getMaxSelectionRow());
                System.out.println("Lead: " + treeSource.getLeadSelectionRow());
                System.out.println("Row: " + treeSource.getSelectionRows()[0]);
            }
        };
        tree.addTreeSelectionListener(treeSelectionListener);
        String title = "JTree Sample";
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TreeSelectionRow treeSelectionRow = new TreeSelectionRow();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, interesting functions! I will use getLevel() as Anonymous suggested, but thank you too it can come in handy :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `TreeSelectionListener` which handles the `TreeSelectionEvent`, you can use the [`TreeSelectionEvent#getPaths`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeSelectionEvent.html#getPaths%28%29) method to retrieve the selected `TreePath`s. The [`TreePath#getPathCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html#getPathCount%28%29) method returns the depth of the selected path.

You can also ask it directly to the `JTree` (although you will need the listener to be informed when the selection changes) by using the [`JTree#getSelectionPaths`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#getSelectionPaths%28%29) method.